# How to block user out if trial ends but no paid subscription

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, stripe-payments, middleware

I am using [stripe-webhook-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe-webhook-middleware) to handle my [Stripe](https://stripe.com/ca) subscription transactions. I currently have it so the user can select their plan from a `/billing` page then that plan is a 14 day free trial. All this works just fine but I am wondering how I can make it so that when they log in they can't get to anything but the `/billing` page if their 14 days has run out and they have not added their CC details yet. I am using `passport-local` as my auth strategy. this is my login check code:

```
exports.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  }

  res.redirect(req.redirect.auth);
};
```

Which is then called on each route I want the user to be forced to login with.

This is how I call the middleware from above:

```
var stripeWebhook = new StripeWebhook({
  stripeApiKey: secrets.stripeOptions.apiKey,
  respond: true
});
```

I access the plan name by going `plans[user.stripe.plan].name` and the last 4 numbers of their CC by doing `plans[user.stripe.plan].name` but those are within my views templates. You can access the user account anywhere in my app using `currentUser` as a reference. I am not familiar with Stripe and webhooks, some example code or code that I could use/ learn from would be awesome. Heck even pointing me in the right direction would be nice.

My signup code is just super basic and the user is assigned the 'free' plan from elsewhere in the code (having trouble locating it right now on mobile)

```
exports.postSignup = function(req, res, next){
  req.assert('email', 'Please sign up with a valid email.').isEmail();
  req.assert('password', 'Password must be at least 6 characters long').len(6);

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    req.flash('form', {
      email: req.body.email
    });
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }
  // calls next middleware to authenticate with passport
  passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard', // Select redirect for post signup
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash : true
  })(req, res, next);
    next();
};
```

I do have plans to run a `cron` job against my database so that I can tell what users still need to enter their CC info and remind them but sadly that won't get all to input their details. I need to be able to block out those who have not paid yet from using my service after their trial ends. If there is anything else I should add please let me know and I'll include it.

Comment: just check if they have a subscribtion. if not, check that they create the account in the last 14days. if not, block

Comment: @sheplu Would I put that in as a middleware for the initial login route? So in my case once the user logs in they are directed to `/dashboard` or would I need to put it on every route? Would a good way to do this be, using the `isAuthenticated ` I have up above and changing that to have what I need?