# Set trial date on stripe dashboard only refer to plans not create them in my app using stripe

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, trialware

Not sure if the title makes sense, I will say this question is very similar to the one I posted yesterday but no response on seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899249/how-to-block-user-out-if-trial-ends-but-no-paid-subscription?noredirect=1#comment80745855_46899249). I have a user sign up and select a plan, once they are set to said plan there is a trial day limit set using the stripe dashboard. I am not creating the subscriptions via the API. Once the day 30 days are up, how can I tell? Only way I can think of telling is checking if their account is older than 30 days and doesn't have a stripe token/last 4 numbers of their CC. There has to be a better way that is more secure and prevents them from canceling their card and still being able to use the service. I know there is no code in this post and should be, but the only code I think is relevant is in the linked post you should check out.

I should add, where should I put this code in my routes? And I am using node.js, express, swig, and stripe.

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking, do you mean how to do the subscription flow with some trial days? "I am not creating the subscriptions via the API." the subscriptions are created manually by someone?

Comment: Are you using Stripe's built-in Subscriptions or handling the subscription logic on your own? If the built-in subscriptions product, the subscriptions have a `status` parameter --- it'll be `trialing` while in a trial and `active` when the subscription is active. presumably, if the user removed or cancelled their card, the subscription would fail when you try to charge it at the end of a trial and you could catch that with webhooks https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/lifecycle

Comment: @RistoNovik I am creating the plans in the Stripe dashboard then assigning users to those plans. I currently have `silver`, `gold` and `platinum` as my plans. When I user selects the plan they want they are then assigned to it. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @duck I am not exactly sure how it is handled. I got most of it from a template/ boilerplate, was the wrong move but too far invested now to back out of this dumb idea to save time.... Now I have a file for the stripe-webhook-middleware package on NPM. I am not too sure how much of the other stuff is done. I would post my github link but I messed up and put an important password in that I am waiting to reset (takes 7 days...). [This](https://github.com/eddywashere/node-stripe-membership-saas) is the boilerplate I used

Comment: @Kirbytech you have to add the handling in the webhook side https://github.com/eddywashere/node-stripe-membership-saas/blob/master/server/middleware/stripe-events.js

Comment: I went and had a look at the stripe docs and I went into the webhook testing area of the dashboard, it says that I need a url to be called. I know it has to be a post but with the middleware from above, how do I figure out routes? The docs are useless in saying what routes, I know the file you linked responds with a 2XX status code (200 in this case) as stripe requires. I am guessing I can put my code for dealing with json in that file. I just don't know how to test it to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is Stripe Events. When an action happens on your account, Stripe issues an "event". You should set up a webhook in your dashboard, and an endpoint on your site or app to capture Stripe Events and process the data that is sent.

Stripe issues two perfect events for what you need: `customer.subscription.trial_will_end` which fires three days before the trial ends , and `customer.subscription.updated` which fires in multiple cases, including when the status is changed from `trialing` to `active`.

Read through the Stripe docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#events) to learn more.

Comment: I read the docs and if I am right to access the `customer.subscription.updated status` it would be just `status` it doesn't look nested to me, so I would just reference it as `req.body.status` and check to see if it is trialing and if so then save that under my user model and reference the model in my auth middlware (seen in the post linked in OP)? So that if the `user status = canceled` or something other than `trialing` or `active` then I would redirect them to the billing page and flash a message to them.

Comment: Sure, I suppose... The implementation is up to you. I'm just letting you know that Stripe provides you a way to check for the end of a trial period on subscriptions.

Comment: Reason I ask is this is way beyond what I have done before so learning it all new. How would you implement it if it were your project?

Comment: @Kirbytech That's an entirely different question, and one you should experiment with first. Search for webhooks here on Stack Overflow as a good starting guide. It's not that new of a concept if you already know node.